# How to use bash script to replace keys with values in files by using a property file as the input

Tags: bash, properties, properties-file

I have several configuration files with configurable data within them. Example (look at `${ConnectorPort}`):

```
<Connector port="${ConnectorPort}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" server="MyServer"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

In config time, I'd like to replace the keys with the values from a given properties file.

The problem is that it takes a **long time** (a few seconds per file) to iterate over all the files and iterate over all the properties to check for replacement for each property. Script below.

Any idea how to do it faster using bash?

Perhaps there's a way in sed or awk to get all properties as a single input?

Perhaps do the replacement in memory?

Script:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    # echo ------
    #echo In file: $file
    #echo ------
    cp -f "$file" "$file.bak"
    unset replaced
    for prop in "${!props[@]}"
    do
        key="$prop"
        keyToReplace="\${$prop}"
        val="${props[$key]}"
        # echo In prop: $key=$val
        sed -i "s|$keyToReplace|$val|Igw $file.change" "$file"
        assertReturnStatus $? "sed failed"
        if [ -z "$replaced" ] && [ -s "$file.change" ]; then
            replaced=true
            echo Replacing props in file "$file"
            cp -n "$file.bak" "$file.orig"
        fi
    done
    rm -f "$file.change"
    rm -f "$file.bak"
done
```

* One of the requirements is to create a backup (.orig) if a file is changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using XML parser like xmllint

Comment: @anubhava - I prefer to keep the keys/values as simple as I can. Hence the properties file.

Comment: Oh, and the configuration files to be replaced can be anything, from XMLs to JSON.

Comment: For sure you could improve performance if you avoid `sed -i` inside your script. In place editing of sed actually creates a backup of file , writes a new file and then moves newfile in place of the old file. You could try to use `sed >newfile` inside loop, and when you are finished you can manually `mv newfile oldfile` (as sed does internally).

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou - I did some tests and couldn't find any performance issue with `-i`. On the contrary. The fact that I need to do a file copy on every property, makes the script even slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop inside the loop causes `sed` to run multiple times for each file. So, get rid of the loop inside the loop.

```
declare -a sedArgs

for prop in "${!props[@]}"
do
    key="$prop"
    keyToReplace="\${$prop}"
    val="${props[$key]}"
    # echo In prop: $key=$val
    #sed -i "s|$keyToReplace|$val|Igw $file.change" "$file"
    sedArgs+=("-e")
    sedArgs+=("s|$keyToReplace|$val|Ig")
done

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    # echo ------
    #echo In file: "$file"
    #echo ------
    sed -i.orig "${sedArgs[@]}" $file
    cmp -s "$file" "${file}.orig" && mv "${file}.orig" "$file"

done
```

Comment: Excellent. I tweaked it a bit to echo if file is replaced: `if cmp -s "$file" "${file}.orig"...`

Comment: This solution was problematic when running on gitbash (on windows). The backup file (.orig) had different end of lines than the originals, causing the appearance as if all files were replaced.

Comment: You could use `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` on the created file to alter the line terminations. Alternatively, a variation of `diff --strip-trailing-cr -q "$file" "${file}.orig" > /dev/null` might work.

Answer (score 0):

An in-memory solution, reading the content to memory and doing the replacement in memory:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
#   echo ------
#   echo In file: $file
#   echo ------
    unset replaced
    contentOrig=`cat "$file"`
    content="$contentOrig"
    for prop in "${!props[@]}"
    do
        # No need to search for all properties if there are
        if [[ ! "$content" == *'${'* ]]; then
            break
        fi
        key="$prop"
        keyToReplace="\${$prop}"
        val="${props[$key]}"
#       echo In prop: $key=$val
        content="${content//$keyToReplace/$val}"
        assertReturnStatus $? "sed failed"
    done
    # TODO: Show warning if `${` still exists (Excluding `*.sh` files). We might have forgotten to add a property.
    if [[ "$content" != "$contentOrig" ]]; then
        let "filesReplacedCount++"
        cp -n "$file" "$file.orig"
        echo "$content" > "$file"
        echo Replaced props in file "$file"
    fi
done
```